# Bootstrap modal not working in asp website that uses a master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a webform that references a master page. When I try to set up a modal form bootstrap. The page won't open the modal.

when I try to toggle the modal with a console:

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle')
```

I get "Object doesn't support property or method 'modal'"

I created a form that does not use  master page and it works.

Comment: How are we to know that you  included bootstrap js?

Comment: Using an ASP.NET master page alters the naming of your elements, assuming you're using the various WebForms controls.

Comment: @Popnoodles I did. It worked on the web-form that did not have a master page and I copied and pasted the head. I am not using webforms controls it is just plain html, and css.

Comment: It's still impossible for anyone wanting to help to diagnose the problem. There isn't enough information given to solve the problem. The only piece of code you've given is a line that works when used in the correct environment.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, 
I found out that the master page didn't load the javascript.Had to load it like this.

" type="text/javascript" />